Azure App Service Deployment keeps creating subfolder upon deployment
For some bizarre reason, every time I deploy my web app on Azure, it creates a folder named "b" within the wwwroot folder of the app service, where it then places the artifact zip file.
I can't find any setting on Azure that would cause the creation of this subfolder, and I can't find any information about this online.

I've been able to work around this issue by setting the physical path in my azure web app to "site\wwwroot\b", and running a post deployment script to cd into that directory:
However, now I've noticed that if I create an App_Data folder inside the "b" folder, which I wanted to add for persistent data throughout deployments, the Azure app service pipeline will now create another subfolder called "b" within the existing "b" folder.
In theory I could just cd into the next b subfolder, but I feel like I shouldn't even have to do this to begin with.
Here's my release pipeline:
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'PAYG(guid)'
    WebAppName: AppName
    ScriptType: 'Inline Script'
    InlineScript: |
     cd b
     unzip AppName.zip
     rm AppName.zip
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
    AdditionalArguments: '-skip:objectName=dirPath.absolutePath=wwwroot' //this is something i tried in an attempt to force the root folder but didn't work
    RenameFilesFlag: false
  continueOnError: true

Any ideas? I'm at a loss for where to look.

Hi there, May I assume your actual concern in this post is why and how the subfolder b under wwwroot is created? It is not from the artifacts zip file, right? From the current information, it doesn't seem to be created this by the pipeline. Can you please let us know if your app is a Windows or Linux app? Is WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set as 1? If deploying via other tools like the Azure CLI command az webapp deploy --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --src-path <filename>.zip in Cloud Shell or from local PowerShell, will the issue still persist?

Have you added any startup command for your app by the way?

Yes, the artifact zip file itself has the website content directly, the b folder gets created when the app service moves the zip file to the wwwroot folder, but before extraction.
Where can I find WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE - I believe the deployment type is set to Web Deploy if that's what this is related to?
No startup commands for the app.
I will try the CLI method and see if the issue persists

@AlvinZhao-MSFT I've tried the CLI way, and the issue still persists, zip gets dropped in wwwroot/b/AppName.zip

Appreciate for your taking to post your findings and solution, which may help others with similar issues on their build artifacts. Thx again for the sharing and cheers!

The issue was that the build pipeline I had was archiving twice, once on .net publish, and once on archive files task. Removing the archive task resolved the issue.
